# ASP.Net which user account running Web Service on IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, windows-server-2008

I want to know which account running my Web Service/Application so that I can assign the read/write access to that account. I have researched and see most of the sources mentions about ASPNET account, but on my 2008 server, there is not any acount named ASPNET. Some sources say ASPNET is being replaced by NETWORK SERVICE?

Also, can I assign to another user account to run the service? And how to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: This blog touches on your issue and may steer your in the right direction: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/02/13/goodbye-network-service.aspx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Look at the Identity of the Application Pool that's running your application.  By default it will be the Network Service account, but you can change this.

At least that's how it works on 2003 server, don't know if some details have changed for 2008 server.

Comment: Still that way for 2008 R2

Answer (score 52):

Server 2008

Start Task Manager
Find w3wp.exe process (description IIS Worker Process)
Check User Name column to find who you're IIS process is running as.

In the IIS GUI you can configure your application pool to run as a specific user:
Application Pool
default
Advanced Settings
Identity

Here's the info from Microsoft on setting up Application Pool Identites:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Comment: -1: Isn't your answer pretty much the same as the accepted answer?

Comment: I found this question when looking for the same info for a 2008/ii7 migration.  The accepted answer didn't give me enough specific info, so I came back and added what I'd found after doing more searching.

Comment: In Windows Server 2012, you'll need to right click IIS Worker Process and click Go to Details to see what user it is running under. Happy to help.

Answer (score 8):

You are most likely looking for the IIS_IUSRS account.

Comment: Just a heads up, that's actually a group, not a user account.

Answer (score 2):

I had a ton of trouble with this and then found a great solution:

Create a file in a text editor called whoami.php with the below code as it's content, save the file and upload it to public_html (or whatever you root of your webserver directory is named). It should output a useful string that you can use to track down the user the webserver is running as, my output was "php is running as user: nt authority\iusr" which allowed me to track down the permissions I needed to modify to the user "IUSR".

```
<?php
  // outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
  // (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
  echo 'php is running as user: ' . exec('whoami');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the right user that needs to use temp folder.
In my computer I follow the above link and find the special folder
c:\inetpub, that iis use to execute her web services.
I check what users could use these folder and find something like these:
computername\iis_isusrs

The main issue comes when you try to add it to all permit on temp folder
I was going to properties, security tab, edit button, add user button
then i put
iis_isusrs

and "check names" button

It doesn´t find anything
The reason is the in my case it looks ( windows 2008 r2 iis 7 ) on pdgs.local location
You have to go to "Select Users or Groups" form, click on Advanced button,
click on Locations button and will see a specific hierarchy

- computername
- Entire Directory
- - pdgs.local

So when you try to add an user, its search name on pdgs.local.
You have to select computername and click ok, 
Click on "Find Now"

Look for IIS_IUSRS on Name(RDN) column, click ok. So we go back to "Select Users or Groups" form with new and right user underline

click ok, allow full control, and click ok again.

That´s all folks,
Hope it helps,

Jose from Moralzarzal ( Madrid )