# Which IIS Account should I grant directory access privileges to?

Tags: security, iis, windows-7-x64, user-accounts, filesystem-access

I've moved my codebase to a new directory and need to grant the IIS account read/write privileges on a few folders to allow access by the ASP.Net runtime. I believe NETWORKSERVICE is no longer used for this purpose (as mentioned in this earlier question: 
[ASP.Net which user account running Web Service on IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269431/asp-net-which-user-account-running-web-service-on-iis-7)) but, try as I might I can't seem to be able to add the IISAppPool/IIS Worker Process the article links to.

I've found a **MyDomain/IIS_WPG** account but this isn't the one that is listed in Task Manager for the **w3wp** process. Can someone help?

UPDATE:

Even odder - the Application Pool for the website in question uses the LocalSystem identity which I thought would be able to access pretty much the entire machine. Is there something incorrect about my basic machine/Windows setup?