# Queries work in debug mode but not in deployment mode?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

I have a C# application and the following is an excerpt from my Web.config file:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=MACHINENAME\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
```

In the code itself, I have a query like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string InsertField(string str1, string str2, string str3)
{

    string sql = @"
          UPDATE DBNAME.dbo.TableName SET Field2 = '{2}', Modified_At=GETDATE() WHERE Field1 = '{0}' AND Field2 = '{1}';

          IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
              INSERT INTO DBNAME.dbo.TableName (Field1, Field2, Field3, Modified_At)
              VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', GETDATE())
            ";

    sql = String.Format(sql, str1, str2, str3);

    try
    {
          string ConString = Constants.connString;
          con = new SqlConnection(ConString);

          cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
          con.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          return "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
          return x.Message;
          //Response.Write(x);
     }

}
```

My web application runs perfectly fine when I debug it but when I publish it, the queries fail. Debugging with Firebug yields the following error:

```
{
    "d": "The UPDATE permission was denied on the object "TableName", database "DBName", schema "dbo".\r\nThe INSERT permission was denied on the object "TableName", database "DBName", schema "dbo"."
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a pretty obvious error. You need to make sure that whatever account your web is setup to run as should have access to update/insert the given table.

As the user seems to not have been set up in the connection string. It will use whatever the web method is running as. So, [find out what that account is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269431/asp-net-which-user-account-running-web-service-on-iis-7) and [grant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) the appropriate perms. It worked in development because it was probably running under your account, which probably had full access to your dev database.

Answer (score 1):

The user doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the update in your prod environment.
You have to grant update permission to the user you are running as