# What's the account to run Asp.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports-2008

I have an asp.NET web app which application pool is .NET 2.0
I have following code to generate PDF file(with crystal report):

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
 Response.WriteFile(PDFFileName)
```

it puts a pdf file on a specific folder.

It's working fine for long time. but after network changed, it is not working anymore. I guess it is permission issue. With about code, which account should have the write permission on the folder? Is it ASPNET Account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net which user account running Web Service on IIS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269431/asp-net-which-user-account-running-web-service-on-iis-7)

Answer (score 2):

could be ASPNET or could be NETWORK Service
it depends on what your app pool settings are set to for the user account. 
Go into IIS manager and find the app pool your application is running on and see what the account setting is. This is what your website will run under and thus the folder you are writing too will require the account added to the permissions.