# Access denied while trying to write file to a location

Tags: c#, file, file-io, console-application, file-permissions

I am trying to write a file to a specific location on a shared folder. 
This shared folder is accessible to only few people. But in the code, I want to take either windows credentials or give certain username and password.
But, when I try it always shows me Access denied.
I want to pass certain credentials or windows network login credential. How can I achieve that ?

```
            string destFilename = @"\\test.net\excel\docs\test.xls";
            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            WebDownload w = new WebDownload(3600000);
            UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] data = w.DownloadData();
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(destFilename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(destFilename, data); //ACCESS DENIED
```

**EDIT**

It is a console application

Comment: ASP.NET does not run as the user who's logged in. You'll need to set up IIS to run it as a specific account which has access, or possibly grant the user that asp.net runs under permission to the folder ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269431/asp-net-which-user-account-running-web-service-on-iis-7) )

Comment: That is not always true. If the web server is on a corporate domain and the web site is set up to use Integrated Windows Authentication, then the web page does run as the calling user. Not saying that is the case, but the OP did not specify.

Comment: I'm not positive what you mean, but I'm still pretty noobish, so I'll take your word for it :)

Comment: If it is a console app you should remove the asp.net tag

Comment: I think a console app would run with the permissions of the logged in user. Not sure though.

Comment: How can I get but. i want to impersonate user

Answer (score 0):

You can setup IIS Application Pool Identities in order to run the application as the user that has access. You can find more information here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities